# Initializing a struct in C

Tags: c, struct

Im having trouble initialising structures (well doing everything actually, but structures first). The struct is first made in a header as follows

```
typedef enum cell
{
    BLANK, RED, CYAN
} Cell;    
#define NAMELEN 20

typedef struct player
{
    char name[NAMELEN + NULL_SPACE];
    Cell token;
    unsigned score;
} Player;

void initFirstPlayer(Player * player);
void initSecondPlayer(Player * player, Cell token);

#endif
```

=======================================================================

and I tried to initialise it here

```
void initFirstPlayer(Player * player)
{
    int randNo = rand() % 2;
    if (randNo == 0) {
        token = RED;
    }
    else() {
        token = CYAN;
    }


    player ; p1 = {
    "placeholder",
    token,
    0,

    }
}

void initSecondPlayer(Player * player, Cell token)
{ }
```

What is the correct way to initialise this player struct?

Comment: What's `player ; p1 = {`? What were you tryng to say by this sequence of tokens?

Comment: `else() {` --> `else {`, `player ; p1 = {
    "placeholder",
    token,
    0, }` --> `*player = (Player){
    "placeholder",
    token,
    0 };` (Also `Cell token;` need)

Comment: player I thought is the struct, and p1 is an instance of that (meaning player 1)

Comment: @Adam: Your struct type is called `Player` or `struct player`. There's no such type as `player` in your program. `player` in your function is a pointer to an instance of `Player`. In any case, regardless of what you thought, it is not clear what sense `player ;` is supposed to make. What is that `;` doing there?

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/GntKAe)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY When I need to overwrite specific values in Player, how do I do that?  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: E.g `char name[NAMELEN + NULL_SPACE]; unsigned score; ...input it... strcpy(player[0].name,  name);`, `player[0].score += score;` something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this should work for you.  Use a generic `initPlayer` function.  Use that to allocate memory for the player and set the initial values.  Be sure to also include a `freePlayer` function where you `free()` the player when you're done.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

Player* initPlayer()
{
    Player* player = malloc(sizeof(Player));
    int randNo = rand() % 2;
    if (randNo == 0) {
        player->token = RED;
    }
    else {
        player->token = CYAN;
    }

    const char* initName = "placeholder";
    strcpy(player->name, initName);
    player->score = 0;

    return player;
}
void freePlayer(Player* p)
{
    free(p);
}
```

The way you'd use this would be like so:

```
int main()
{
    Player* p1 = initPlayer();
    Player* p2 = initPlayer();

    play(p1, p2);

    freePlayer(p1);
    freePlayer(p2);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, the `token` of `p1` and `p2` need to be different from each other.

Comment: Then just pass some condition as an argument to `initPlayer()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have at least C99 support, so that compound literals and designated initializers are available to you, then you can use:

```
void initFirstPlayer(Player *player)
{
    *player = (Player){ .token = rand() % 2 ? CYAN : RED,
                        .score = 0,
                        .name  = "placeholder"
                      };
}
```

This does a structure assignment to the variable whose address is passed to the function.  It compresses it all into one statement; you can split it out into several if you wish.  This is an occasion where the ternary `? :` operator is useful.  You might prefer `(rand() % 2)` with the extra parentheses; I'd probably add them as often as I'd omit them.

The compound literal comes from `(typename){ ...initializer for typename... }`.

The designated initializers are the `.member = value` notations.

If you're stuck with C90 support, you have to work harder, perhaps creating a local variable with the correct information and then doing the structure assignment.

```
void initFirstPlayer(Player *player)
{
    Player p1 = { "placeholder", rand() % 2 ? CYAN : RED, 0 };
    *player = p1;
}
```

Now the onus is on you to list the initializers in the correct sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to receive the player you want to inicialize as parameter:

```
void initPlayer(Player* player)
{
    int randNo = rand() % 2;
    if (randNo == 0) {
        player->token = RED;
    }
    else {
        player->token = CYAN;
    }
    const char* initName = "placeholder";
    strcpy(player->name, initName);
    player->score = 0;
}

int main() {
        Player p1;

        initPlayer(&p1);  
}
```

You can have an array of players or allocate dinamically with malloc.